# Ansible - how to target item

Tags: ansible

I want to target the path variable in this output of Ansible.

```
ok: [myMachine1] => {
    "foundFiles": {
        ...
        "results": [
            {
              ...
                "files": [
                    {
                        ...
                        "path": "/my/first/path",
                        ...
                    }
                ],

            },
            {
                ...
                "files": [
                    {
                        ...
                        "path": "/my/second/path",
                        ...
                    }

            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I tell Ansible to target the 'path' variables.
I'm trying with:

```
   - debug:
    msg: "{{ item.files.path }}"
  with_items:
    - foundFiles.results
```

But only getting `"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'key'`

Thanks guru's.

Answer (score 1):

First: bare variables are not supported since Ansible 2.2
Second: `files` is a list in your example

```
- debug: msg="{{ item.files[0].path }}"
  with_items: "{{ foundFiles.results }}"
```

If you have multiple entries under in `files` list, you should consider to `map` it.